# Got Error in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

If I upload more than 5 mb file using retrofit in my android app I get this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
 W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:80)
 W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1xStream.java:286)
 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll(RealBufferedSink.java:104)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:118)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:704)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:563)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:241)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
 W/System.err:  ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The server you are connecting to has closed the connection for whatever reason. You need to speak to the people who run the server and see what's happening. Could be an invalid request, broken server, invalid format, etc. This isn't a problem with Retrofit

Comment: Have i to talk to godaddy peoples??

Comment: I think there is a limit in filesize with godaddy server.check your server configuration